# Override numpy.random to use cudamat

Tags: python, numpy, cudamat

I have a programm that uses np.random many times. Now I wan't the user to pass an argument `gpu=True/False`. How can I override np.random to return `cm.CUDAMatrix(np.random.uniform(low=low, high=high, size=size))` without ending in a recursion?
Or is there a better way to use cudamat with small code changes?

Thanks for your help.

If you need more code please comment.

```
class FeedForwardNetwork():

    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, dropout=False, dropout_prop=0.5, gpu=True):            
        np.random.seed(1)
        self.input_layer = np.array([])
        self.hidden_layer = np.array([])
        self.output_layer = np.array([])
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.dropout_prop = dropout_prop

        r_input_hidden = math.sqrt(6 / (input_dim + hidden_dim))
        r_hidden_output = math.sqrt(6 / (hidden_dim + output_dim))

        self.weights_input_hidden = np.random.uniform(low=-0.01, high=0.01, size=(input_dim, hidden_dim))
        self.weights_hidden_output = np.random.uniform(low=-0.01, high=0.01, size=(hidden_dim, output_dim))
```

Comment: Please post more of your code, specifically the np.random method or class. You can simply overload the method but I will need to see what the arguments are.

Comment: The two last lines are the important ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class FeedForwardNetwork():

def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, dropout=False, dropout_prop=0.5, gpu=True):            
    np.random.seed(1)
    self.input_layer = np.array([])
    self.hidden_layer = np.array([])
    self.output_layer = np.array([])
    self.input_dim = input_dim
    self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
    self.output_dim = output_dim
    self.dropout = dropout
    self.dropout_prop = dropout_prop

    r_input_hidden = math.sqrt(6 / (input_dim + hidden_dim))
    r_hidden_output = math.sqrt(6 / (hidden_dim + output_dim))

    self.weights_input_hidden = np.random.uniform(low=-0.01, high=0.01, size=(input_dim, hidden_dim))
    self.weights_hidden_output = np.random.uniform(low=-0.01, high=0.01, size=(hidden_dim, output_dim))

def np_random(self, gpu):
   '''gpu:bool'''
     if gpu:
         return np.random.uniform(low=-0.01, high=0.01, size=(self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim))
    else:
         return np.random.uniform(low=-0.01, high=0.01, size=(self.hidden_dim, self.output_dim))
```

Then you can call it from your instance:

```
instance = FeedForwardNetwork(**kwargs)

instance.np_random(True/False)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there no way to really override np.random so I do not have to change all the code to np_random?

Comment: If you import numpy as np then no I don't think you can because anything starting will look in the numpy library. That being said if you change the numpy library you can certainly override that method.

Comment: Okay that was all I wanted! Thanks for your help.